# Is Raspberry Pi Using the Same Coding and Encoding in Live Video Streaming as in Ubuntu and on other Machines?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, webcam, picamera

Recently, I have been tagged to work with the Raspberry Pi 4, and with the action camera that I have plugged to work with it as a webcam. However, the Live Video that is streamed through Raspberry Pi is much darker than it was tested on Ubuntu, and other different machines. The settings are always the same on the camera itself, however, the exposures are not. By the way, the application cheese is being used on all of the devices that were mentioned. If the coding and encoding are different, we need to change our way. Please inform me about it. Have a good day ahead!

Comment: 'however, the exposures are not.' Sounds like that is the culprit?

Comment: The exposures in the settings of the camera is also the same

Comment: I mean the output on the laptops are different

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen that is what I meant, the settings are the same for all

Comment: I actually thought you meant the exposure of the light in the location of the camera.
I wouldn't expect any difference, so there is a software diff.